# Print When (last element reached) Expression in JasperReports

Tags: formatting, jasper-reports

Is it possible to generated a "Print When Expression" that detects the last element in an XML datasource file?

Basically I have a report with a column break inserted after a sub-report in a detail band so I can clearly define new pages for the beginning of a new record. But it always leaves me with a blank last page. So I am hoping that I can prevent this if I have a print when condition that prevents the column break if it is the last record element in the XML datasource.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't know it's the last element until after you look for the next element. I don't think there is a simple way.

In principle it should be fine to do something like this: 
Create a super-report around the entire report. Run the same query in the super-report. Count the rows. Then pass the number of rows to the original report (which is now a subreport) and re-run the query again. Clearly, running the query twice is another drawback.

If the data source were SQL, then I would suggest modifying the SQL to return the number of rows as part of the result set. But for non-SQL data sources, you need some way of knowing the number of rows (well... some way of identifying the last row) before you reach the last row.

Comment: Another possibility is to create two variables: `previous` and `current`.  Declare `previous` before `current`. Set the **Expression** for `previous` to `$V{current}`; leave **Initial Value Expression** blank. Set the **Expression** for `current` to the `$F`ield value. Now PrintWhenExpression: `$V{previous} == null` should be triggered only when on the last row. Might need `!$V{current}.equals($V{previous})` as well.

Comment: I'd like to contribute with my own workaround. I simply pass as a parameter the number of records to be printed, say RECORDS_NUMBER. Then, in the report I create a boolean variable which expression is $V{REPORT_COUNT} == $P{RECORDS_NUMBER}. After that, you already can use de new variable in any 'Print When Expression' whose content you need to be printed after the last record.

Answer (score 0):

Many years late...
if you sure your datasource is a JRBeanCollectionDataSource, you could use:

```
$V{REPORT_COUNT} == ((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource)ORIGINAL_DATA_SOURCE( )).getData().size()
```

Comment: Can you double check? It gets flagged as an invalid expression.

Comment: Yeah, it complains but it works. You need to ensure you Datasource is a JRBeanCollectionDataSource. You can see the type using ORIGINAL_DATA_SOURCE( ).getClass()