# How to find out out the total rows and show/hide a column value in iReport 

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am using iReport 4.5

What I am trying to do is to show/hide the column value of the first and last column value something like the following...

Pet | Name

- {empty}    Ben
- Dog        Bill
- Cat        Sophie
- Cat        {empty}

Does anyone know how I can do this?

I have read about printWhenExpression but not sure how to get in advance the row count in my table?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The request seems strange. You just want to hide the last name regardless of who it is? Maybe a little more explanation is needed.

Comment: yes it is strange but fits my scenario what i have looked into is the <printWhenExpression>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find it very easy to hide the first pet. Use a standard Print When Expression. Something like this:

```
$V{REPORT_COUNT} > 1 ? $F{Pet} : ""
```

Hiding the last element is harder. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981334/print-when-last-element-reached-expression-in-jasperreports).

Comment: thanks yes that was what is was thinking of by not sure how to find which is the last row and hide it ....

Comment: I will probably do what you suggest in your other answer using a count in SQL statement. Thanks